# What does "hog log" mean and where does it come from?

Tags: idioms

I recently read the following line (**emphasis mine**):

> What **hog logs** or sacred cows in the organization should we eliminate?

I gather from the context that "hog log" probably means something like a single point of failure, but I'm not sure.

What does "hog log" mean in this context?

Re: those asking for citation. This line came from an organization email from a native English speaker.

Comment: I've never heard the expression.  Have encountered a few boars in my years in corporate America, though, wild and otherwise.

Comment: The only thing I got when I Google'd "hog log" was farming and firewood equipment.  In the context of IT, I'd suspect the writer may have meant "log hog"?  Just guessing....

Comment: Cite to what you read?

Comment: "hog" refers to a greedy person (a parasite feeding at the expense of others). "log" is used for  someone/something inert, heavy, not sentient.

Comment: @deadrat: See edit. Can't exactly cite.

Comment: I've only heard the term "hog leg" as old slang for an unusually large side-arm, typically a revolver. Dirty Harry's 44 caliber Magnum, for example

Comment: Great!  Ask the send what he meant.

Comment: Now that I've seen it I'm surprised it isn't a sausage or double entendre.

Comment: Well, [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hog+log) says a wad of chewing tobacco.

Comment: I'm not convinced that management is looking to get rid of wads of chewing tobacco in the organization or an abundance of sausages :-)

Comment: @AndyG - Well, next time they raise the subject, ask them to just spit it out.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "hog laws"?

Those are rules that everybody follows that have not basis, but have kept being followed out of tradition.

So they are not real laws, they are precedent.

Since the phrase included "sacred cows", I bet that is what the person meant. "Hog logs" was a typo.

Comment: Do you have a cite?  The only reference I can find that's close is a claim that hog laws are those that the police make up to to arrest of cite someone.  (*Hog* is possibly a synonym for the slang "pig" for a cop, but I've never heard it used like that.)  The point though is that nobody follows them, so everybody is vulnerable.  Of course there are actual hog laws, which were of more importance when pig owners let their animals wander in city streets.